# Copy every prefixed element except one in XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt

I was given a XSLT-file which looks like this (only the relevant part):

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
            xmlns:xls="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
            xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
            xmlns:step="http://www.stibosystems.com/step"
            xmlns="http://www.stibosystems.com/step"
            exclude-result-prefixes="xs xls">

<xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    <xsl:copy-of select="$newShopDoc/STEP-ProductInformation/AttributeList/Attribute[starts-with(xs:string(@ID), 'PA_')]" />
</xsl:copy>
```

I also tried this approach, as suggested:

```
<xsl:copy-of select="$newShopDoc/STEP-ProductInformation/AttributeList/Attribute[starts-with(xs:string(@ID), 'PA_')][not(@ID='PA_VENDOR')]" />
```

Now there was a change-request, to copy *all* elements, except one in particular. All elements are prefixed with a `PA_` and so is the element, which shouldn't be copied. There are like 100 elements, so I really don't want to write every single element I need and leave out the one I don't need.

I read a bit into it and thus far, I can only see a solution in building a sub-structure with an `if` condition.

From what I saw though, there might be a solution with parentheses and the `and` keyword, but I havn't found the solution.

I'm not familiar with XSLT and there is probably an easy way to achieve my goal.

The element I want to exclude is called `PA_VENDOR`. Is it also possible to exclude more than 1 element, even though it isn't yet requested?

Comment: The answer depends on which version of XSLT your processor supports. In XSLT 2.0 you can use the `except` operator.

Comment: unfortunatly, it is 1.0. I updated the question. I hope that `version` in the `stylesheet`-attribute corresponds to the XSLT-version.

Comment: Not necessarily. The XSLT author is supposed to match the stylesheet's version to the processor's capability. To test the processor, see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/25245033/3016153

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without a *reproducible* example, all we can do is guess.

Looking at the code you already have, I would guess that your description:

> All elements are prefixed with a `PA_` and so is the element, which shouldn't be copied.

is incorrect. The instruction:

```
<xsl:copy-of select="$newShopDoc/STEP-ProductInformation/AttributeList/Attribute[starts-with(xs:string(@ID), 'PA_')]" />
```

copies all **elements** named `Attribute` that have an **attribute** named `ID` that starts with `PA_`.

Guessing further that the element you don't want to be included in this is also named `Attribute` and its `ID` attribute contains `PA_VENDOR`, you would need to change the instruction to something like:

```
<xsl:copy-of select="$newShopDoc/STEP-ProductInformation/AttributeList/Attribute[starts-with(@ID, 'PA_')][not(@ID='PA_VENDOR')]" />
```

---

Untested, because we have nothing to test against.